# ERROR from UglifyJs Unexpected token keyword, expected punc

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting the following error when trying to run `npm install` on my project: `ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token keyword «function», expected punc «,»`

I'm aware it's because I'm trying to use an ES6 feature, but I think something is wrong with my setup which is why it isn't getting compiled to ES5 by Babel.

I've looked at a number of problems on SO regarding the issue, and I've incorporated some of those answers, but none has solved the problem.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": {
        "node": "8.9.1"
    },
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
        "postinstall": "NODE_ENV=prod webpack -p"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.1.18",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-player": "^1.1.2",
        "react-render": "^1.2.1",
        "webpack": "^3.11.0",
        "yargs": "^11.0.0"
    },
    "babel": {
        "plugins": [
            "transform-react-jsx"
        ],
        "presets": [
            "es2015",
            "react"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0"
    }
```

}

and my `webpack.config.babel.js`

```
var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/static",

  entry: {
    client: ['./App.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + "/static/build"
  },
  resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /(\.js$)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: [
                'react',
                ['es2015', {'modules': false}]
            ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried with `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0` and then add it to the `query object ` inside `webpack.config` like `stage-0` https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/

Comment: So, adding that, and additionally `babel-polyfill` (to satisfy an error that arises) works. I also noticed that simply removing the `postinstall` script in `package.json` works. Why do these solutions work?

Comment: Well `babel-preset` is a set of plugins used to support particular language features.

Comment: where is this `include: /\.min\.js$/` coming from? your output seems to only produce bundle.js. Have you tried without the `include` option?